# 403 error access denied even with correct perissions using Microsoft Graph api with the PHP SDK when accessing calendar events

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am having trouble accessing calendar events of users using the Microsoft Graph api and get a access denied response even though I have set all of the correct permissions and more, both application and delegated for (Calendars.Read Delegated, Calendars.Read Application, Calendars.Read.Shared Delegated, Calendars.ReadBasic Delegated, Calendars.ReadBasic.All Application, Calendars.ReadWrite Delegated, Calendars.ReadWrite Application, Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Delegated). I am using the microsoft developer instant sandbox users who all have Microsoft 365 E5 Developer licences and all have Exchange Online Plan 2.

The code I use to retrieve the access token and send the calendar request is below:

```
$guzzle = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token';
$token = json_decode($guzzle->post($url, [
    'form_params' => [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'scope' => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ],
])->getBody()->getContents());
$accessToken = $token->access_token;

$graph = new Graph();
$graph->setBaseUrl("https://graph.microsoft.com/")
    ->setAccessToken($accessToken);
$ptr = $graph->createCollectionRequest('GET', '/users/{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}/events')
    ->setPageSize(100);
```

If I use the same code with the endpoint /users/{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}/calendars I get a list of the users calendars but as soon as I try to get events I get a 403 error. The same issue occours if I use the deligated auth flow and try to access events as a signed in user, again I am able to access a list of calendars.

When decoding the access token the roles section looks like this:

```
"roles": [
    "Calendars.Read",
    "Mail.ReadBasic.All",
    "Group.Read.All",
    "User.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadBasic.All",
    "GroupMember.Read.All",
    "Calendars.ReadWrite",
    "Mail.Send"
  ]
```

Are there other permissions that need to be set for an app or a user to make this work?

Let me know if I can add any more info to help with answers, sny sugesstions would be helpful

Thanks

*UPDATE*

Having looked further it could be an issue with "Limiting application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access)

There was a policy defined but having removed this (and waiting for that update to become effective) I am still getting the same error. I assume therefore that a policy is needed to allow access however I can't find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix (given here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1167148/microsoft-graph-throwing-403-error-for-calendar-wi) is to only have the lowest level permission, otherwise you get the error response.